# Model with custom table doesn't save, in Laravel 3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-3

I have an eloquent model, that is using a custom table, coming from the user table.

Like so...

```
class Appointment extends Eloquent
{   
   public static $table = null;
   public function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();

       // Here I load the custom table, from the user table
      // Pull the prefix of the table, and append
      // This works perfectly fine for viewing the data
      static::$table = Auth::user()->tenantTable()."_appointments";
   }

   public static $connection = 'tenant-data';
   public static $timestamps = true;
```

I can pull, and view the data perfectly fine with this setup.  So every user, has their own appointment table.

However, if I change anything and then use eloquent save() method.  I get a recursive call, that never ends.

What do I need to change in laravels save() method to get this to work?

And do I have to change it in the core?? Or can I override the save() method in the current model?  And if so, how?

Comment: Are you really using Laravel 3? Laravel 5 is out now.

Comment: @ceejayoz Im aware.... but Im not about to port the whole site over just yet.  Just adding a few multi-tenant additions.  Dont have the time or resources for it.

Comment: Good question. I wonder how many people there are who still remember Laravel 3 :)

Comment: @KyleK Just checking. Haven't seen a L3 question in ages!

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost just guessing but did you try to change the order of your constructor commands? First set the table dynamically and then call parent constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to achieve but, yes you can override parent ( eloquent's on your case ) save method.

```
class Appointment extends Eloquent{  
   public function save(){
      //Do your own save stuff 
      ....
      // call Eloquent's save function to finish
      parent::save();
   }
}
```